# IE WebDriver exception Cannot change value of readonly element

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I can not set form field value for IE (11.0)

When I try 
`$(By.name(key)).setValue`
I get exception "Cannot change value of readonly element"

[image]

Methods `getValue(), clear(), isAvailable()` works.

[image]

Also `setValue()` good works with chrome WebDriver

Comment: If possible please try to post the relevant HTML code. It can help us to understand the issue properly. Did you try to use the code instead of evaluating it? Did that work? Is the element Read-only? Which application software you are using for making this test?

Comment: I can show only part HTML code
`<form id="testForm" action="" method="POST" name="xxxForm" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <table border="1" class="inputFieldsTable" id ="commonElementsTable">
    <tr>
      <th align="left">description</th>
      <td><input type="text" name="description" value="DVD Movies" size="80"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>`
It is ordinary field, the field has no CSS styles.
I can edit this field manually and chrome WebDriver can do it too.
I use InternetExplorerDriver by Silenium, java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find workaround for IE.
Instead `$(By.name("desc")).setValue("123")` I use

```
$(By.name("desc")).clear;
$(By.name("desc")).sendKeys("123");
```

It works for IE and other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.